# How much data is there in which partition in Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka and I have a single broker node in which I have created one topic with 1 replica and 1500 partitions. I have pumped lot of data in this particular topic. Now is there any way, I can figure out how much data is there in which partition?

I am not sending any key while sending data to the kafka so I know it will choose partition in a round robin fashion but I want to see how much data is there in each of those 1500 partitions. Is there any way to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Run command:

> bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list host:port --topic your_topic --time -1

The result lists each partition's offset, which can be thought of produced message number.

Comment: Ok so I see something like this `topic:1103:2976` so what does this mean? I think this partition is 1103 but what is 2976 here?

Comment: It means the latest offset if you specify time as -1.